# triggering jquery event within an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, event-handling, hotkeys

Here's the situation:  I have an edit box that is actually an iframe.  I do not want to add any code to the iframe itself.  The iframe has no id.. However it does have a parent div that i can use to identify it.

I have hotkeys set up to trigger events in my page.  When I am focused on the iframe none of the events trigger.

Is there a way to unfocus the iframe and trigger the event via hotkeys?  What can I do to execute javascript from the parent document when I am clicking inside the iframe?

Comment: Iframes are meant to be very isolated from the containing page, and vice-versa. There are ways around this but you'll find that you're constantly fighting it. It will almost certainly be easier if you use, say, a `<div>` instead of an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 2):

if the contents of the iframe are from the same domain only then can you access it, else you will be getting a cross domain security error. If its the same domain, then following jQuery code can access it. Ad an id to the iFrame and then.

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#yourElement")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use the script in iframe